# Proof that the discrete metric $d$ is complete in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, self-learning

This is an attempt of a proof of a rather basic result.

> **Proposition:** The discrete metric $d$ is complete in $\mathbb{N}$.
>
> ***Proof:***
> Let $x_n$ be an arbitrary sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ endowed with its natural discrete metric, and assume it to be Cauchy. Thus, by the definition of Cauchy sequence in a generic metric space $(X, \rho)$, for every $\varepsilon >0$  there is a $N \geq 1$ such that, for every $k, l \geq N$, $\rho (x_k , x_l) < \varepsilon$, that, when applied to a space endowed with the discrete metric $d$, gives rise to the fact that there is a $N \geq 1$ such that, for every $k, l \geq N$, $d (x_k , x_l)=0$. Hence, $x_n$ converge, and $\mathbb{N}$ is complete.

As I wrote, the result is fairly obvious, but I was wondering about my way of writing it, and of course also about the content, *i.e. the fact that I don't actually show how the limit looks like, but simply point out that it has to exist*.

As always, any feedback regarding anything will be more than welcome.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For discrete metric: $x_\lambda\to x\iff x_\lambda\equiv x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take out the second sentence. Instead, apply the definition of a Cauchy sequence to $(x_n)$, taking $\epsilon = 1/2$ in (or any other positive number less than $1$). The use the definition of the discrete metric to get $x_k = x_N$ for all $k \ge N$. This will show that your Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ is eventually constant with limit $x_N$.

Comment: First of all, thanks. I see what you mean. Thus, would you consider mine as a redundant, but still ok, proof?

Comment: @Kolmin It's better to name the limit, namely $x_N$, explicitly. Then you can fall back on the definition of convergence.

Comment: I agree with Henno. If you do that, then the proof will be clearer.

Comment: Maybe something one should point out explicitly in the proof is that $x_N\in \mathbb{N}$, since the limit always exists in the completion.